# How to make SeekBar interface with code?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I've created a few SeekBars in a fragment and an OnSeekBarChangeListener in my java file, but there seems to be an unexplained disconnect between the xml layout and the java file.

java class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);
    final SeekBar s1 = (SeekBar) root.findViewById(R.id.s1Bar);
    final TextView spicinessText = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.spicinessTxt);
    s1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            spicinessText.setText("Spiciness " + String.valueOf(i));
        }

        @Override

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);
}
```

xml layout

```
<FrameLayout>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Spiciness"
    android:id="@+id/spicinessTxt"/>


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/s1Bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sourness"/>


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sweet"
    android:id="@+id/sweet"/>


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Salty"/>


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
```

I launched the app on an external device and the actual layout simply doesn't communicate with the java code, even though I'm pretty sure I've done it all correctly. If anyone can see whatever critical error I've made here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you launched fragment on activity??

Comment: I used a fragment for the java class.

Comment: Hey @kyle can you please share your project with me??

Comment: @ankit how would that help you?

Comment: Because I am not getting problem that you are facing. So kindly share your project with me only. So I will resolve your problem. Otherwise it's your wish.

Comment: Alright. How do I share it with you?

Comment: Share me on Gmail...here is my I'd ankitpatidar030@gmail.com

Comment: @ankit ok i sent it to you.

Comment: @ankitpatidar I would like to know if you are going to attempt to look through my project and find the error, and if you received the file properly. Thank you!

Comment: Yes I received.

Comment: Hey @kyle, problem is solved. I mailed you with code and explanation what is actual problem. Is there anything to solve? so i can do that too

Comment: @ankitpatidar that worked! thank you! if you want me to accept your answer, you have to post one first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for your query:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 { 
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment      
      View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false); 
      final SeekBar s1 = (SeekBar) root.findViewById(R.id.s1Bar); 
      final TextView spicinessText = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.spicinessTxt); 
      s1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
      {
           @Override 
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) 
           {
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                spicinessText.setText("Spiciness " + String.valueOf(i)); 
           } 
           @Override 
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
           { } 
           @Override 
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
          { } 
      }); 
     return root;
  }
```

Thanks and happy coding.